# Transcent StoreJet auto backup

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Is it possible to make Auto-backup button on my Transcend StoreJet 35T3 work? I need this option badly. As an external hard drive it works perfectly, but I cannot find any software to make the button work.

Comment: Any news on the topic? I'm going to buy this HD and would like to know if you found out a solution, meanwhile. Thanks

Comment: I opened a new thread about the feature which however excludes all graphical backup systems here http://askubuntu.com/q/796966/25388 I think it is a driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

[This isn't really an answer, but I hope it will be in the near-future]

I'm also using a StoreJet drive. I've noticed that the kernel has a drive called `ums-onetouch` ( http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.19.1/drivers/usb/storage/onetouch.c ) that is supposed to support the hardware button on Maxtor drives, and maybe it can be used to also support the StoreJet.

The driver currently has the Maxtor drives' identifiers hard coded, to it won't work out of the box, but maybe just adding the StoreJet identifiers will be enough to get it to work for the Transcend drives.